# django - resizing horizontal filter for group admin page

Tags: django

I'm trying to resize the horitontal filter for default group admin page because it is too small.
Here is what I've tried:
admin.py:

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('permissions',)
    class Media:
        js = ('js/group_admin.js',)

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

group_admin.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#id_permissions_from").css("height", 600);
  $("#id_permissions_from").css("overflow", "scroll");
  $("#id_permissions_to").css("height", 600);
  $("#id_permissions_to").css("overflow", "scroll");
})
```

It's not resizing and is not showing any javascript error.
If I run the javascript above in the console it works fine; so there must be something wrong with the order of javascripts getting loaded.
I'm using django 1.8.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out a proper solution to the timming issue so here is a workaround:

```
function resize(){
  $("#id_permissions_from").css("height", 600);
  $("#id_permissions_from").css("overflow", "scroll");
  $("#id_permissions_to").css("height", 600);
  $("#id_permissions_to").css("overflow", "scroll");
}

$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resize()
  }, 1000);
  //resize();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with .js or with .css also.

try this for js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#id_permissions_from").css("height", 600);
      $("#id_permissions_from").css("overflow", "scroll");
      $("#id_permissions_to").css("height", 600);
      $("#id_permissions_to").css("overflow", "scroll");
})
```

or with .css, but then you have also add your css to class media

```
#id_permissions_from{
    "height": 600;
    "overflow": "scroll";
}
#id_permissions_to{
    "height": 600; 
    "overflow": "scroll"
}
```

and your class in admin should look like this

```
class Media:
        js = ('js/admin/my_own_admin.js',)    
        css = {
             'all': ('css/admin/my_own_admin.css',)
        }
```

Comment: I tried the css approach too and it does not work. The problem is that django is running another piece of code either css of javascript that is overriding it. I even tried adding !important to force the style but it is not working.

Comment: What's the error ? What does the console say ? Are your styles loaded correctly ? Are they visible inside your template ?

Comment: That's the difficulty. There are no javascript or css errors and they are getting loaded fine because if I put an alert in the javascript, it runs.